# grouped bar plot with percentages where variables are different across groupings

Tags: r, ggplot2

using this example I can plot a nice grouped barplot that expresses the percentages of finance agreements (credit, audit, free) across three groupings (Associates,Masters,PhD):

```
StudentData <- data.frame(degree = sample( c("Associates", "Masters", "PhD"), 100, replace=TRUE),
                          category = sample( c("Audit", "Credit"), 100, replace=TRUE))

StudentData2 <- data.frame(degree = sample( c("PhD"), 50, replace=TRUE),
                          category = sample( c("Free"), 50, replace=TRUE))

StudentData<-rbind(StudentData,StudentData2)


ggplot(StudentData, aes(x=degree, group=category, fill=category)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=..prop..), stat="count", position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1),labels = scales::percent) +
  ylab("Percent of Sample")
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

but the percentages are actually how the three finance groupings are distributed among the groupings. i.e. anyone who is on a "free" plan is doing a PhD.

What I would like is to express the percentages as a the percentage within each grouping, rather than total number. By looking at:

```
summary(StudentData[StudentData$degree == "PhD",])

        degree     category 
 Associates: 0   Audit :18  
 Masters   : 0   Credit:14  
 PhD       :82   Free  :50
```

We see that only `50/82` PhD students are on a Free program, so I would like to have grouped bars that would reflect this instead i.e. `Free:50/82 Credit:14/82 Audit:18/8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aggregate the data beforehand and use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()`.

```
StudentData %>%
  count(degree, category) %>%
  group_by(degree) %>%
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=degree, y = prop, fill=category)) + 
  geom_col(position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1),labels = scales::percent) +
  ylab("Percent of Sample")
```

[image]